# Angular Library extend 3rd party component

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components, angular-library

I have an angular library that is using Telerik for styling.  In this library I am creating a set of filters (i.e. customer filters).  I have a custom component that uses the `<kendo-multiselect></<kendo-multiselect>` attribute. `<kendo-multiselect>` is a component from the telerik angular npm package.

What I am wanting is the ability to have a custom component where whoever uses this component, they can add the additional telerik properties from the 3rd party telerik angular package without me having to create @input elements to map them.

Example:
kendo-multiselect has a Filterable attribute. It's a true/false value, so I don't really need to program for it as it is all handled in 3rd party kendo-multiselect component, but I would like to have the user pass it through to the custom component.  This way they can have access to all 100 customizable attributes without me having to create 100 @inputs.

So `<lib-customer-filter [Filterable]="true"></lib-customer-filter>`.

What I am needing is to somehow have that filterable attribute automatically put in my custom component's template `<kendo-multiselect></kendo-multiselect>`.

I get this is a simple example, but let's say there are 100 attributes that go along with the kendo multiselect. I don't want to have to program every single one of them, I want the user to be able to set the properties and use those features without me having to program it.

Is this possible with Angular Components?

**EDIT**

I've seen there is ng-content.  I'm wanting that exactly, except ng-attribute or something similar. So it'd look like this.

Custom Component

```
selector: lib-customer-filter
template:`<kendo-multiselect ng-attributes></kendo-multiselect>`
```

Using Custom Component

```
<lib-custom-filter [Filterable]="true"></lib-custom-filter>
```